# issues with using the <s:Form/> tag in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a simple Form containing two input boxes. as shown in the code below :

```
<s:Form>
    <s:FormItem width="242" label="Name:">
        <s:TextInput x="1" y="0"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem width="242" label="Evaluate at:">
        <s:TextInput/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

the problem is the input boxes are y distances apart and i want to bring them a little bit closer. if i had used the `<s:VGroup/>` or `<s:HGroup/>`, there is the gap property to close up the gap but that property is not in the Form tag.

How can I close the gaps using the Form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Flextras' way of doing it (I don't like it because I'm not a fan of AS code for layout stuff), or you can do this:

```
<s:Form>
    <s:layout>
        <s:FormLayout gap="0" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:FormItem width="242" label="Name:" height="25">
        <s:TextInput x="1" y="0"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem width="242" label="Evaluate at:" height="25">
        <s:TextInput/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Comment: even if you set the FormLayout gap property to "0", you still have that gap. what you are actually setting to zero is the layout not the TextInput components. imagine just using a <s:VGroup gap = "2"> tag where the TextInput are created inside the VGroup tag. then the gap is close enough but with the <s:Form/> tag, even with a formLayout gap of 0, the gaps are still wide...

Comment: @henry joseph, one quick fix is to set the explicit height of the form item (like I just did).  I'm not a fan of this and personally, I would just create a custom FormItemSkin and have it added to all FormItem's through css.

Answer (score 2):

The way I did it was to create a skin for all my forms. Then in CSS I set the skin I created to be the default form skin.

1. Copy FormSkin create YourFormSkin.mxml
2. Copy FormItemSkin create YourFormItemSkin
3. Modify the gap in YourFormSkin.mxml
4. Modify contentGroup LEFT property in FormItemSkin.mxml, change `contentCol:0` would be the least gap. The numbers are relative to the columns setup by the form layout.

Create or edit your CSS file to include:

```
s|Form{
    skinClass:ClassReference("your.project.view.skins.YourFormSkin");
}
s|FormItem{
    skinClass: ClassReference("your.project.view.skins.YourFormItemSkin");
}
```

Now you can customize every form in your application by just editing your two skin files.

Answer (score 0):

[FormItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/FormItem.html) is a container, and extends [SkinnableContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableContainer.html).  As such, it uses a layout class; and the [gap property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0141D24B-6AEB-4721-BA04-9BF15F86350F.html#WS817a894fd7827b2a-209375481211babd9df-8000) is usually set on the layout class.

So, assuming you're using one of the layouts that support the gap property, you can do something like this:

```
myFormItem.layout.gap = myNewGap;
```

Comment: This is true, but the Spark form skin also uses a custom layout called a "form item layout" and it's basically rows/columns setup. The items within the skin use positioning relative to those columns/rows which means a LOT of the gap is actually in the skin file. For example, the form item skin has a `contentGroup` spark group that has its own vertical layout w/ gap as well as its own position `bottom="row1:5"` which means you get 5pixels of gap at the bottom of your form item content. labelDisplay also has that.